# C# Optimizing Linq query: Update with where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

How would I optimize the following query? We are reviewing entity framework queries in database, and trying to learn.

```
        using (var context = new DataDbContext())
        {
            var query = (from u in content.Parents
                         where u.Children.Any(y = y.Age > 13)
                         select u);

            foreach (var parent in query.ToList())
            {
                foreach (var children in owner.Children)
                {
                    children.IsTeenager= true;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think it needs optimizing?

Comment: You may want to check the age in the inner loop; that might not update what you want it to.

Comment: This seems simple enough. You can't update records without querying first. The only alternative would be skipping entity and executing an SQL update statement directly.

Comment: The logic is a little odd. Set all owner's pets to `IsTeenager = true` if *any* pet they own is over 13?

Comment: This looks like a common N+1 Entity Framework problem. It's also peculiar that you set the `IsTeenager` property at all, that should be calculated based on the `Age` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to optimize, you can reduce the code. The logic is kinda odd

```
using (var context = new DataDbContext())
{
    foreach (var child in content.Parents.Where(o => o.Children.Any(x => x.Age > 13)).SelectMany(o => o.Children))
    {
        children.IsTeenager= true;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or

```
using (var context = new DataDbContext())
{
    var parents = content.Parents.Where(o => o.Children.Any(x => x.Age > 13));
    foreach (var child in parents.SelectMany(o => o.Children))
    {
        children.IsTeenager= true;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no great way to simplify what you are doing here. EF tends to push you down the path of reading a bunch of data from the data store, updating the entities locally and then writing those changes back. This is obviously quite slow. However, what you're trying to do here is get all children and set the `IsTeenager` property so you don't even care about the `Parent` object, you can simply do this:

```
var children = context.Children.Where(c => c.Age < 13);

foreach(var child in children)
{
    child.IsTeenager = true;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, there is a much easier way to do this using raw SQL. For example:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Children SET IsTeenager = 1 WHERE Age < 13");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(from u in content.Parents
  where u.Children.Any(y = y.Age > 13)
  select u);
```

This seems to be a bug. If `Parent` had a child that was 14 and another that was 9 both would have `IsTeenager` set to true. Conversely if they had a single child who was 13 that child would not have Teenager set to true.

If possible then I'd make `IsTeenager` a computed property rather than a stored value

```
public bool IsTeenager => Age >= 13 && Age <= 19
```

Then I'd never have to call the query at all.

Failing that I'd change the query to

```
content.Parents.SelectMany(o => o.Children).Where(o => o.Age >= 13 && o.Age <= 19)
```

Possibly I could skip the indirection entirely with the likes of.

```
content.Children.Where(o => o.Age >= 13 && o.Age <= 19)
```

Depending on the structure of the database. Do I really need to go via parents?

Unless I knew that `IsTeenager` was always going to be false when the query ran, I'd could filter those that don't need it set with:

```
content.Parents.SelectMany(o => o.Children).Where(o => !o.IsTeenager && o.Age >= 13 && o.Age <= 19)
```

Or

```
content.Children.Where(o => !o.IsTeenager && o.Age >= 13 && o.Age <= 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the following in your comments earlier (has since been deleted):

> it was a job interview question I had few months ago, not even sure

If I were to ask someone this question in a job interview I would hope they would inform me of the following:

---

1. Age, and IsTeenager, should be dependent on each individual entity and not computed over a collection.
2. You should make sure that the person's / child's Date of Birth is persisted and not the age. Otherwise you have no idea when the age changes for an entity as the age is only valid on the date and time the entity is captured in the system.
3. IsTeeneger should not be persisted, it should be derived based on the Date of Birth value. If it is only ever checked in the c# code and you don't have to query against it then make it a model only getter field that is **not** mapped in Sql. If you need to query against it make it a computed column is the database schema. The same should be done for `Age`!
4. Parent and Child could better be modeled as Person with a recursive one-to-many relationship Children. This way you can also do grand parents who have children who have children.

### Model Only

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            var today = DateTime.Today;
            // Calculate the age.
            var age = today.Year - BirthDate.Year;
            // Go back to the year the person was born in case of a leap year
            if (BirthDate > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
            return age;
        }
    }
    public bool IsTeenager
    {
        get
        {
            return Age >= 13 && Age < 20;
        }
    }
}
```

### Mapped to a computed column

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; } // should be computed and mapped from sql
    public bool IsTeenager { get; set; } // should be computed and mapped from sql
}
```

Comment: The logic for `IsTeenager` as written isn't that the 'child' is over 13, it depends on its siblings' ages too.

Comment: @CharlesMager Yeah, that's almost certainly wrong too.

Comment: @DavidG I'd guess as a job interview question they're just looking for you to spot the select N+1 issue. But who knows?!

Comment: @CharlesMager - If I asked this question I would be more pleased if someone could point out all the logic and design mistakes instead of just looking at the N+1. That is just me though.

Comment: @CharlesMager Yup, I'm beginning to think it was a bad idea to answer this question myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update data using Entity Framework, you've to retrieve it first into the memory (either by eager loading or lazy loading) and then modify it.
Sometimes it causes N + 1 problem. That means N + 1 calls to the database server. And if you use some cloud based hosting like Azure or AWS then you're charged per request. So that would be costly financially as well.

In your case, i would prefer to do this in Yes Entity Framework, but using Stored Procedure. Plain queries are used but i won't recommend you to do it in that way.

Using Stored Procedure will save you from bringing data into the memory and achieve the result using 1 database call.